# Most recent version of SQL Server Management Studio that works with Windows 7 pre SP1?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssms, windows

I am trying to do some work with SQL Server 2008 (not 2008 r2, just 2008) that is installed on a Windows 7 Pro 32-bit PC. It's just Windows 7 with no Service Pack 1 applied. I have no option to update the PC, can only use it as it is now.

I am trying to find a version of SQL Server Management Studio that will install on this PC. Does anyone know?

I tried v17.9.1 but I got an error saying that Win 7 SP1 is required. Unfortunately I have no option to install SP1 and the computer has no access to the internet either.

What was the last version that DID install on just plain Windows 7?

Cheers.

Comment: do you have the install media for sql server 2008. that version came with SSMS in the installer

Comment: It's low likelihood someone will be able to tell you what outdated version of SSMS will work on your end of life unpatched Windows 7 machine unfortunately. Is this for some legacy database on a work machine?...how big is the database and can it be moved to a newer machine to work with in the interim?

Comment: @BobKlimes Yes I tried doing that with I think it was SQL Server Configuration Manager but it asked me to direct it to the install media and I don't know where it is? If I knew the file name I could search for it myself. I tried pointing it to: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server` and a few other places. I found a version of SSMS 2008 online I can try that. Someone suggested trying Version 16.5.3 since v17.0 required at least Win7 SP1 but I would like to confirm if v16.5.3 needs SP1 or not.

Comment: @J.D. Yes it's hooked up to a weather monitoring system installed years ago. No plans or chance to upgrade any part of it anytime soon. Just want to add a feature to it myself. That's a good idea to copy the DB and work with it locally. Not a big DB but not sure how to copy it, need to google about that now!

Comment: pretty sure this will have ability to install ssms (make sure you only choose ssms install) https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438

Comment: Theoretically if you disable the SQL Server service, you should be able to copy and replace the MDF and LDF files of the database. If I get a chance I'll write up a more detailed answer.

Comment: @BobKlimes I followed your link and downloaded SSMS for SQL Server 2008 R2. It installed and works with SQL Server 2008 on my Win 7 Pro 32-bit PC that does not have Service Pack 1. If you would like to make this as an answer I will accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSMS for 2008 came with the install media of SQL Server. You can download [SQL Server 2008 R2 Express](https://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30438) and just choose to install SSMS. You should be able to connect to SQL 2008 with SSMS 2008 R2.